# Fetching non-utf8 data with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, utf-8, xmlhttprequest

I want to fetch a document from the web with `xmlHttpRequest`. However the text in question isn't utf8 (in this case it's windows-1251 but in the generic case, I wouldn't know that for sure).

However, if I use `responseType="text"` it treats it as though the string is utf8, ignoring the charset in the content-type (resulting in a nasty mess).

If I used 'blob' (probably the nearest thing to what I want), could I then convert that to a DomString taking into account the encoding?

Comment: `ignoring the charset in the content-type` Are you sure, the server correctly reads the file as windows-1251, serves it as such, and responds with the correct content-type? If anyone of these three fails, you might end up with alphabet soup, before even a single byte arrived the browser.

Comment: `convert that to a DomString taking into account the encoding` I'm not aware of an api/lib for that, but worst case, you can map each byte to the proper char.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I actually found an API which does what I want, from here:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/08/Easier-ArrayBuffer-String-conversion-with-the-Encoding-API

Basically, use `responseType="arraybuffer"`, pick the encoding from the returned headers, and use `DataView` and `TextDecoder`. It does exactly what is required.

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
xhr.onload = function() {
  const contenttype = xhr.getResponseHeader("content-type");
  const charset = contenttype.substring(contenttype.indexOf("charset=") + 8);
  const dataView = new DataView(xhr.response);
  const decoder = new TextDecoder(charset);
  console.log(decoder.decode(dataView));
}
xhr.open("GET", "https://people.w3.org/mike/tests/windows-1251/test.txt");
xhr.send(null);
```

```js
fetch("https://people.w3.org/mike/tests/windows-1251/test.txt")
  .then(response => {
    const contenttype = response.headers.get("content-type");
    const charset = contenttype.substring(contenttype.indexOf("charset=") + 8);
    response.arrayBuffer()
      .then(ab => {
        const dataView = new DataView(ab);
        const decoder = new TextDecoder(charset);
        console.log(decoder.decode(dataView));
      })
  })
```

Answer (score 4):

> If I used 'blob' (probably the nearest thing to what I want), could I then convert that to a DomString taking into account the encoding?

https://medium.com/programmers-developers/convert-blob-to-string-in-javascript-944c15ad7d52 outlines a general approach you can use. To apply that to the case of fetching a remote document:

- Create a [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to read in the fetch response as a `Blob`
- Use [`FileReader.readAsText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText) to get back text from that `Blob` in the right encoding

Like this:

```js
const reader = new FileReader()
reader.addEventListener("loadend", function() {
  console.log(reader.result)
})
fetch("https://people.w3.org/mike/tests/windows-1251/test.txt")
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(blob => reader.readAsText(blob, "windows-1251"))
```

Or if you instead really want to use XHR:

```js
const reader = new FileReader()
reader.addEventListener("loadend", function() {
  console.log(reader.result)
})
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.responseType = "blob"
xhr.onload = function() {
  reader.readAsText(xhr.response, "windows-1251")
}
xhr.open("GET", "https://people.w3.org/mike/tests/windows-1251/test.txt", true)
xhr.send(null)
```

> However, if I use `responseType="text"` it treats it as though the string is utf8, ignoring the charset in the content-type

Yes. That’s what’s [required by the Fetch spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-body-package-data) (which for this is what the XHR spec relies on too):

> Objects implementing the `Body` mixin also have an associated package data algorithm, given *bytes*, a *type* and a *mimeType*, switches on *type*, and runs the associated steps:
>   … 
>   ↪ **text**
>               Return the result of running [UTF-8 decode](https://encoding.spec.whatwg.org/#utf-8-decode) on *bytes*.

Comment: I missed that note in the fetch spec. Thanks.

The reason for using xmlhttprequest is to find out what the encoding is.