# Unable to read accents of "latin1" encoded file with d3.dsv

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a csv file (separated by semicolons so i use d3.dsv to read it)

```
d3.dsv(";", "Project.csv", function(d) {
    console.log(d)
});
```

But i get "�" where the accents are.

I know the file is "latin_1" encoded so i tried this :

```
dsvReader = d3.dsv(";", "iso-8859-1");
dsvReader("Project.csv", function(d) {
    console.log(d)
});
```

But i get the following errors :

```
> net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first snippet: The d3-fetch function `d3.dsv` uses `response.text()` on the result of `fetch`, which only handles UTF-8.

Your second snippet: You try to fetch the file named `iso-8859-1`, which presumably does not exist. There is no argument in `d3.dsv` which accepts encoding.

One solution is to make sure the server has a UTF-8 file, and not a Latin-1 file. This is the simplest solution: in 2022, there are very few legitimate reasons to not use Unicode.

Another is to use `fetch` yourself, or use [`d3.buffer`](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch#buffer) or [`d3.blob`](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch#blob), then convert the response to UTF-8 yourself, as described in [Fetching non-utf8 data with XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753212/fetching-non-utf8-data-with-xmlhttprequest) using `TextDecoder` (on buffer) or `.readAsText` (on blob), and finally use [`d3.dsvFormat(";").parse`](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv#dsv_parse) on the now correct data.